# Zend Framework 2: Hostname and redirection

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-route

I need to create a route in a zend framework 2 project that helps me to create these url:

- http://username.test.com and .net
- http://www.test.com and .net

**Code:**

```
<?php

return array ( 
    'router' => array ( 
            'routes' => array ( 
                    'username' => array (
                            'type' => 'hostname',
                            'options' => array (
                                    'route' => ':username.test.:tld',
                                    'constraints' => array(
                                            'username' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                            'tld' => '[com|net]*',
                                    ),
                                    'defaults' => array (
                                            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                                            'action' => 'show',
                                            'tld' => 'com'
                                    )
                            )
                    ),


                    'home' => array (
                            'type' => 'hostname',
                            'options' => array (
                                    'route' => 'www.test.:tld',
                                    'constraints' => array(
                                            'tld' => '[com|net]*',
                                    ),
                                    'defaults' => array (
                                            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                                            'action' => 'index',
                                            'tld' => 'com'
                                    )
                            )
                    ),

            )
    ),
```

In some case when I call the http://username.test.com url I need to redirect the user to the http://www.test.com by the url helper.

**update**:

For instance the zfUser has a specific routes to serve the user:

- /user
- /user/register
- /user/logout

When I execute this code when the application starts from the http://username.test.com

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url('zfcuser') ?>" title="Profilo"><i class="fa fa-user"></i><?php echo $this->translate('Your Profile') ?></a>
```

It creates a links like these:

- http://username.test.com/user
- http://username.test.com/user/register
- http://username.test.com/user/logout

and I would like this:

- http://www.test.com/user
- http://www.test.com/user/register
- http://www.test.com/user/logout

How I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" here is that you want to set the ZfcUser routes as the children of your `home` route. However, ZfcUser sets just routes as root and not as child_routes of yours.

The solution is is using "prototypes" and the `chain_routes` key. It is pretty undocumented, but you can read some info in [this PR](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/pull/3999#issuecomment-22403173).

Basically, transform your top-level routes ("home" and "username") to a prototype and set the `chain_routes` key for the ZfcUser route.